# type inference causes code to fail

Tags: types, typescript, type-inference

consider the following code:

```
var yum: HTMLElement;
  var bin: Element;
yum = document.createElement('p');
var y: Node = yum.cloneNode(true);
bin.appendChild(y);

y.style.display = 'none';     //fails Error 2   Cannot convert 'Node' to 'HTMLElement': Type 'Node' is missing property 'click' from type 'HTMLElement'
```

of course this fails as cloneName returns Node and not HTMLElement and if you try what to convert manually from Node to HTMLElement then the same error occurs. So I stuck as I do not see a way to change the opacity. Now this is javascript I was trying to move into Typescript.

Answer (score 3):

If you know that the element being cloned is an HTMLElement as in your example, you can cast it:

```
var yum: HTMLElement;
var bin: Element;

yum = document.createElement('p');
var y: HTMLElement = <HTMLElement> yum.cloneNode(true);
bin.appendChild(y);

y.style.display = 'none';
```

Where the type is explicit, you could opt not to annotate the types, like this:

```
var bin: Element;
var yum = document.createElement('p'); // type inferred as createElement returns an HTMLElement
var y = <HTMLElement> yum.cloneNode(true); // type inferred from the cast

bin.appendChild(y);
y.style.display = 'none';
```